# How to reduce the λ-matrix to Smith Standard Form

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

```
A = {{1 - λ, 2 λ - 1, λ},
     {λ, λ^2, -λ}, {1 + λ^2, λ^3 + λ - 1, -λ^2}}
```

How to reduce the above λ-matrix to the following Smith standard form:

```
{{1, 0, 0}, {0, λ, 0}, {0, 0, λ^2 + λ}}
```

Comment: `SmithDecomposition` works if lambda is numeric.

Comment: The following kglr's answer solves my problem, but I don't know where to get built-in functions that are not shown in help documents like Control`PCS`SmithForm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Control`PCS`SmithForm[A, λ] // MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  1 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & \lambda  & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & \lambda  (\lambda +1) \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Comment: I'd like to ask you where you get built-in functions like ``Control`PCS`SmithForm`` that are not shown in the help documents

Comment: @Gowiththewind, I used ``??*`*SmithForm*``

Comment: @Gowiththewind actually, you'd better use \\`  to type ` ,or the effect will not be so good.

Comment: @wuyudi Okay,thank you very much for your suggestion.

Answer (score 6):

The Wolfram Function Repository has a [(recently added) function](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PolynomialSmithDecomposition) for this.

```
amat = {{1 - lam, 2 lam - 1, lam}, {lam, lam^2, -lam}, {1 + lam^2, 
    lam^3 + lam - 1, -lam^2}};

ResourceFunction["PolynomialSmithDecomposition"][amat]

(* Out[3320]= {{{0, -1 - lam - lam^2, 1 + lam}, {0, 
   1 + lam^2, -lam}, {1, -lam^2 - lam^3, -1 + lam + lam^2}}, {{1, 0, 
   0}, {0, lam, 0}, {0, 0, lam + lam^2}}, {{1, 1, 1 - lam}, {0, 1, 
   1}, {0, 0, 1}}} *)
```

It returns three matrices in the form {left multiplier, SNF, right multiplier}

--- edit ---

Since it came up in other responses, I'll say a bit about the relationship between this WFR function and the `` Control`PCS`​ `` functions. They predate the WFR function (obviously). There is a `PolynomialSmithDecomposition` as well as 
`SmithForm`. I believe the latter simply returns the middle matrix from the former (so no computation is saved).

The WFR function is a rewritten variant, and I believe in some cases it will be more efficient. I've not had a chance yet to pass this on to the developer handling the control functionality. Also there remains a question of which version is better to use in the case of polynomials with approximate coefficients. That will require some experimentation. Also it could be the case that the new one is sometimes slower, ergo, more experimentation needed. So this remains a work in progress.

--- end edit ---

Comment: Thank you very much for the function you added in the FunctionRepository.